# A difficulty in understanding the proof of the open mapping theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

The theorem and part of its proof is given below:

[image]
[image]

But I do not understand why in the inequality after (12.10) he used that $||y-b|| \leq \epsilon$, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: He earlier says "let $y\in B_\epsilon(b)$".

Comment: yes thank you :)@LordSharktheUnknown